# Wordpress Reverse Proxy

Tags: wordpress, apache, reverse-proxy

I am trying to reverse proxy example.com  to production.example.com which lives on a different server. However after adding proxy rules (apache) on the main domain and adding below on production.example.com wp-config.php

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', "https://example.com/" );
```

I was able to load the site without any issue. However when i try to click on a post,  the post loads from production.example.com

```
Example : https://production.example.com/hello-world/
```

How can i fix this issue letting the site to load on siteurl instead.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that example.com is your external domain.

In the database (or ui directly) I had to update both `siteurl` and `home`

```sql
update wp_options set option_value="https://example.com" where option_name in ("siteurl", "home");
```

Pasting also the reverse proxy settings for apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/sslcert/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/sslcert/server.key"

   ProxyRequests Off
   KeepAlive Off
   <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
   </Proxy>

   # These are required for https reverse proxy to work   
   RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
   RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"   

   ProxyPass / http://non-public-address/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://non-public-address/
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ErrorLog "logs/wordpress.revproxy-sslerror_log"
   CustomLog "logs/wordpress.revproxy-sslaccess_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```